# Google/Youtube API Server Key format for pre-validation

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Context: I'm updating my WordPress plugin to authenticate against the YouTube v3 API using a server key that has to be requested and entered by the user of the plugin.

Problem: I would like to perform validation of some kind on that key before using it, but can't seem to find documentation of the format a Google API server key adheres to. Based on (a very limited) number of examples it seems as though a key is:

- is 39 characters long
- is case-sensitive
- consists of letters, numbers and at least dashes

So the question, obviously: Is this documented somewhere? Can anyone confirm or expand?

thanks,

frank

Comment: Dashes do not always appear.  Underscores perhaps?  All of mine have had at least 1 underscore.

Comment: I did not see documentation outlining the format of the hash.  It's generated based on a number of other data.  The closest I've seen to validating this would be: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/YgYdJ04hcZI  however that is for a version 2 API KEY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn’t find any published key format either. Maybe because they want to keep the freedom to change the format in the future. If you want to be on the safe side, you should probably just do sanity checks well above the observed format. For example <=1024 bytes and non-control ascii characters, or even base64, or just don’t do any validation at all and let Google do that.

Comment: thanks for that Christian. what do you mean with "or even base64"?

Comment: hmmm, how could one identify a string as being base64-encoded?

Comment: You could check if the length is a multiple of 4, and has A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, and ends in zero to 2 equal symbols.  Then you can also try to decode it in whatever language and catch any errors.  Javascript has to functions for base64 encoding "atob()" and "btoa()"

Comment: thanks, but seems like there's a high risk of false positives, so I don't think I'll do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about taking the key and passing it to a server-side script that attempts to use the key for some call.  Then if it works return a success, else fail and call this async for the validation.  Just seems more reliable than trying to decoded or anticipate the format of the hash.

Comment: He said before using it I am guessing he means before hitting google's server with it.

Comment: indeed, the goal was to pre-qualify the key.

Comment: You could use the mentioned method to prequalify by testing it first.  That is why I mentioned doing this via an async call so you could handle it client-side.